# puppet configuration issue

Tags: configuration, puppet

I'm going over a module and in one of the define statements they call a file resource inside which they have:

```
file { "ifcfg-${interface}":
  content => template('network/ifcfg-bond.erb'),
  before  => File["ifcfg-${interface}"],
}
```

my query is what does the "File" portion mean, where would it look for a file e.g. ifcfg-bond0? Looking at that line it doesn't give any clues.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Stop what you're doing and go read the [Learning Puppet tutorials](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before =>` creates a dependency. So this file has a dependency on itself (which, btw is silly).

templates are located in `$puppetroot/modules/$modulename/templates`

But yeah, these are really basic things in puppet, so please follow Michael's advice and read a tutorial. It'll explain all this and more in much better detail.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that myself that it had a cyclical check, but needed an expert opinion to be sure.